# What is difference b/w org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.encodeForHTML and org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.encodeForJavaScript methods

Tags: java, security, owasp, encoder, esapi

I Know, we can use encodeForHTML for HTMl and encodeForJavascript for javaScript.
There is a Cross-Site Scripting: "Reflected fortify scan problem" in my code

```
String errorDesc = HttpServletRequest.getParameter("error_description");
```

I have to validate this using Encoder but I am confused to use which one should i use between them. As we do not know the return type of HttpServletRequest.getParameter.

```
1.  org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.encodeForHTML
2.  org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.encodeForJavaScript
```

Answer (score 2):

What we have here dear asker is a rather common misunderstanding about the differences between output encoding--which is what you're working with when you look at the Encoder calls, and input validation, which is a completely separate operation that has little to do with the `Encoder` class.

The `Encoder` methods you're dealing with here are to be used only when you're presenting data to a user, and only for the correct context.  For example, if the application is a "Single Page Application" (SPA) then very likely you're just going to want to ensure that the output is encoded for JavaScript as the client-facing framework will almost certainly be JavaScript.

If you were using an older style of application, then you would encode for HTML anytime you were going to place data between `<some_tag> data </some_tag>`.

XSS requires you to understand one thing for *every* variable in your application:  Its data flow, from when the value is generated (Server, User, DB, etc.) and understand all of the transformations it might undergo as it traverses to the user and back to the system.  If the value starts in the browser, it will enter into some kind of Controller on the backend, and before you process the value you'll whitelist validate it--ESAPI has a validator class--and then if it passes validation you'll ensure that the database will only treat it as data (PreparedStatement, or through use of an ORM framework's utilities.)  Best practice is to

1. Canonicalize the data
2. Validate against the canonicalized value
3. If valid, discard the canonicalized value and store the original data

If used properly, the `Validator` class is defaulted to help you do this.

The methods you're asking about in this question are for instances where user input is being sent back to the browser, either from the database or from a previous request in your session that hasn't yet been persisted.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is how the output encoding is done. `Encoder.encodeForHTML()` does HTML entity encoding via the `org.owasp.esapi.codecs.HTMLEntityCodec` class, whereas `Encoder.encodeForJavaScript()` uses JavaScript's backslash encoding via `org.owasp.esapi.codecs.JavaScriptCodec`.

Which one you choose depends on the context of how your "error_description" parameter will be rendered in your application. If it is rendered between HTML tags, use `encodeForHTML()`, if you are rendering it in purely a JavaScript context, use `encodeForJavaScript()`. Refer to https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html for a more thorough explanation of all this.